# Is there any way to make a chipped visual effects on a background in frontend?

Tags: css, reactjs, graph

building a static website with React.

## Description

I want to add a visual effect to the pages of the website, as shown below.

[visual effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE3dF.png)

I am trying to build a rectangular background. Some triangles will be cut from this rectangle (at least two vertices of the triangle must be on the edge before cutting), as shown in the shaded area in the figure.

Then I want the cut out triangles to float randomly in the page.

And I want the background of the content part in the middle (also a rectangle) not to be cut (ie only the outermost padding part is cut).

## Some Attempts

I have tried to randomly generate the vertex coordinates of the polygons after cutting and the vertex coordinates of the cut triangles and display them using css clip-path and animation. But I haven't come up with a usable vertex generation algorithm.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you would have tried `clip-path` generator but might find that not working as expected on different screens. There's no efficient vertex generation algorithm for this. The alternate is to do so some random math by yourself. If you feel that your polygons are nice on one screen but scrambles on other, try using `media` queries.